# Graph based algorithm to move trains on a network using pyhton

Tags: python, optimization, graph-theory

I'm looking for an algorithm which could give me the train movements to perform to position the trains in the good stations doing the less movements.

Here the graph of the network
`

```
`# Matrice représentant les mouvements possibles entre les gares
M = [
  [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
  [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
  [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
  [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
]``
```

I have 8 stations, I'd like to define the current train position as follow
`# Positions actuelles des trains (index de la gare + 1, 0 signifie non présent) train_positions = [1, 4, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`

`here train_position[i]=trainID and i=station, in the example, train3 is in station 3, station 4-8 are empty (no train)`

`# Positions souhaitées des trains (index de la gare + 1, 0 signifie aucune préférence) train_wishes = [1, 0, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0]` 
train_wishes is the wanted position so for example, train3 has to move from station 3 to 4.

Update to clarify the input structure:
I am using 2 vectors (one for start position and another one for end position) with a lengh=number of stations.
I used "0" for empty station and 1....NbrOfTrainsOnSite for the different trains : lets say I have 8 stations and 2 trains on site: 1 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 mens train 1 is on station 1, 2+3+4+6+7+8 are empty and train 2 is on station 5

Any idea how I could implement this problem?
We can considere that the cost between stations is the same =1, so moving from station 1 to 2 is =1, from 1 to 5 is 5, from 3 to 6 is also 1.

as a first step, knowing the movement to do would be great
in a second time I'd like to consider operational conditions meaning that I'm moving trains with a shunter which can take 2 trains at the same time (the shunter is in the middle) and my goal is to avoid to remove the shunter from the rail

I tried to use basic bfs and djikstra algorithm but I don't know how to properly set the problem

Update

I managed to have the BFS working so step 1 is OK, here the code

```py
    import networkx as nx
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from collections import deque
    
    # Définition de la fonction BFS avec mouvements enregistrés
    def bfs_with_moves(train_positions, train_wishes, M):
        initial_state = (tuple(train_positions), [])  # État initial : positions des trains et liste de mouvements
        visited = set()  # Pour suivre les états déjà explorés
        queue = deque([initial_state])  # File pour BFS
    
        while queue:
            current_positions, moves = queue.popleft()  # Prend le premier état de la file
            if current_positions == tuple(train_wishes):
                return moves  # Si l'état souhaité est atteint, renvoie la liste de mouvements
            
            if current_positions in visited:
                continue  # Ignore les états déjà visités
            visited.add(current_positions)
    
            for i in range(len(current_positions)):
                if current_positions[i] is None:
                    continue  # Ignore les gares vides
                for j in range(len(M[i])):
                    if M[i][j] == 1 and current_positions[j] is None:
                        new_positions = list(current_positions)  # Copie des positions actuelles pour modification
                        new_positions[j] = new_positions[i]  # Déplace le train de la gare i à j
                        new_positions[i] = None
                        new_moves = moves + [(i + 1, j + 1)]  # Enregistre le mouvement effectué (indices 1-based)
                        queue.append((tuple(new_positions), new_moves))  # Ajoute le nouvel état à la file
        
        return None  # Si aucune solution n'est trouvée
    
    # Matrice représentant les mouvements possibles entre les gares
    M = [
        [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
    ]
    
    # Noms des gares associés aux indices
    station_names = {
        1: "ITE",
        2: "VES1",
        3: "VES2",
        4: "VES3",
        5: "VED",
        6: "VC",
        7: "VD",
        8: "HALL",
        9: "SKID"
    }
    
    # Noms des trains associés aux indices
    train_names = {
        
        1: "RERNG T23",
        2: "ZEFIRO",
        3: "CDGX",
        4: "RERNG 5"
        # ... Ajoutez les autres noms de trains ici ...
    }
    
    # Positions actuelles des trains (None signifie gare vide, indice du train sinon)
    train_positions = [None, 1, None, 3, None, 4, None, 2,None]
    # Positions finales des trains (None signifie gare vide, indice du train sinon)
    train_positions_final = [None, 3, 2, None, 4, None, None, None, 1]
    
    # Appelle la fonction BFS pour trouver les mouvements nécessaires
    moves = bfs_with_moves(train_positions, train_positions_final, M)
    
    # Affiche les résultats
    if moves is not None:
        print("Movements to be made:")
        train_positions_copy = list(train_positions)  # Copie des positions actuelles pour modification
        for move in moves:
            source_train = train_positions_copy[move[0] - 1]
            dest_train = train_positions_copy[move[1] - 1]
            source_station = station_names[move[0]]
            dest_station = station_names[move[1]]
            print(f"Move train '{train_names[source_train]}' from station {source_station} to station {dest_station}")
            train_positions_copy[move[1] - 1] = source_train  # Met à jour les positions pour les prochaines étapes
            train_positions_copy[move[0] - 1] = None
    else:
        print("No solution found.")
    
    # Création d'un graphe pour le graphe initial
    G_initial = nx.Graph()
    
    # Ajout des noms de gares en tant qu'attributs
    for i, name in station_names.items():
        G_initial.add_node(i, name=name)
    
    # Ajout des arêtes en fonction de la matrice M
    for i in range(len(M)):
        for j in range(i+1, len(M[i])):
            if M[i][j] == 1:
                G_initial.add_edge(i+1, j+1)
    
    # Création d'un graphe pour le graphe final
    G_final = nx.Graph()
    
    # Ajout des noms de gares en tant qu'attributs
    for i, name in station_names.items():
        G_final.add_node(i, name=name)
    
    # Ajout des arêtes en fonction de la matrice M
    for i in range(len(M)):
        for j in range(i+1, len(M[i])):
            if M[i][j] == 1:
                G_final.add_edge(i+1, j+1)
    
    # Création de la figure avec deux sous-graphes
    plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
    
    # Calcul des couleurs des nœuds en fonction des positions des trains
    node_colors_initial = ["orange" if train_positions[i] is not None else "green" for i in range(len(train_positions))]
    node_colors_final = ["orange" if train_positions_final[i] is not None else "green" for i in range(len(train_positions_final))]
    
    # Utilise la grille de sous-graphes (1 ligne, 2 colonnes) pour afficher les deux graphes
    plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
    pos_initial = nx.spring_layout(G_initial, seed=42)
    nx.draw(G_initial, pos_initial, labels=station_names, with_labels=True, node_size=1000, font_size=10, font_color="black", node_color=node_colors_initial)
    for i, train in enumerate(train_positions):
        if train is not None:
            plt.text(pos_initial[i+1][0], pos_initial[i+1][1] + 0.1, train_names[train], ha='center', fontsize=8, color="black")
    plt.title("Graphe de Gares (Initial)")
    
    plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
    pos_final = nx.spring_layout(G_final, seed=42)
    nx.draw(G_final, pos_final, labels=station_names, with_labels=True, node_size=1000, font_size=10, font_color="black", node_color=node_colors_final)
    for i, train in enumerate(train_positions_final):
        if train is not None:
            plt.text(pos_final[i+1][0], pos_final[i+1][1] + 0.1, train_names[train], ha='center', fontsize=8, color="black")
    plt.title("Graphe de Gares (Final)")
    
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

Now I need to consider the locotractor which means that basically I need to introduce more restrictions:

- the shunter can move 2 trains at the same time
- once the first movement is done (shunter on track), the shunter can only move trains which can be get by crossing empty stations. Here an exemple, we are in a straight line, station number from 1 to 5 avec we have a train in 2+3+4, if we move train 2, we won't be able to move 4 since 3 is in between.

Hope I was clear, waiting for feedback

Comment: "the good stations"  I think you mean the "wanted stations"

Comment: There seems to be two questions here.  1) Required movement of trains and 2) movement of trains using shunter.  Unless the there are more constraints than you have mentioned, question 1) is trivial - just use BFS for each train to find shortest path from current to wished for each train.  You do not need Dijkstra since all links have the same weight

Comment: Have you read "How to ask a question"?  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask It includes this advice: After you post, don't run away too fast—leave the question open in your browser for a bit to see if anyone comments. If you missed an obvious piece of information, be ready to respond by editing your question to include it.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, could you explain me better how to set the problem and implement BFS? I never used it before....

Comment: For question 2,  here some more details:  
Trains are not moving alone, we are working on test tracks so we unbrake the trains and we move them with a shunter/locotractor (diesel powered). This shunter is driving on the rail as well as the trains so once this shunter is on the track, we can only moved between free stations.  
Here an example, lets suppose that we have trains on station 1+2+4, we want to move them to station 2+3+5 and the shunter is placed between 1-2, I can easily move to 2+3 but then, due to my graph, I can't move to get the train on station 4 to move to 5.

Comment: Big improvement to your question!  I suggest it would be even clearer if the 1st paragraph read: "Algorithm needed to move trains through a network ( stations and rail links ) from initial positions to specified positions.  Trains move one by one or in pairs.  Trains cannot move through station occupied by a currently stationary train.

Comment: Question: can more than one stationary train occupy a station?

Comment: Question: 'train_wishes = [1, 0, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0]  train_wishes is the wanted position so for example, train3 has to move from station 3 to 4.'  Assuming you are using 1-based indices, this looks like the destination for train3 in station2 because train_wishes[3] == 2

Comment: FYI: I have coded a C++ application to solve these problems when trains are not blocked travelling through stations occupied by stationary trains.  See https://github.com/JamesBremner/shunter

Comment: FYI the shunter application moves trains one by one, while avoiding stations blocked by stationary trains.

Comment: I started to implement the new restrictions but the output isn't optimal at all, I'm also only considerating single train movements with the shunter. Can you tell me the output you get with my latest M matrix and those start/end vectors:
start = [None, 1, 2, None, None, 4, None, None,None]
end = [None, 4, None, None, None, None, None, 1, 2]
I'm not really used to C++, I'll try to get codeblocks or whatever in the next days to give it a try as well.

Comment: Please use VSCODE - then you will be able to use the project files I have provided.

Comment: "my latest M matrix"  What is this?  Is it the matrix in your post here?  The one that I used to generate the adjacency lists here https://github.com/JamesBremner/shunter/blob/7da4caadb29728565610dead95082ef2834ba0d0/src/main.cpp#L32-L42

Comment: I am having trouble with understanding your new start and end positions.  In particular, trains 2,5,7 and 8 ( zero-based indices).  Its hard to explain in a comment.  Please take a look at github issue which goes into more detail https://github.com/JamesBremner/shunter/issues/1

Comment: Please clarify how you specify the train start and end positions.  ( This is the 3rd time I have asked for this.  We need to sort this out before we can continue. )

Comment: I would like to propose a simple file format for specifying the start and end train positions.  Details at https://github.com/JamesBremner/shunter/issues/1#issuecomment-1693387478  Please let me know what you think.

Comment: Hi, your proposal seems OK to me, until now I was using 2 vectors (one for start position and another one for end position) with a lengh=number of stations. I used "0" for empty station and 1....NbrOfTrainsOnSite for the different trains : lets say I have 8 stations and 2 trains on site: 1 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 mens train 1 is on station 1, 2+3+4+6+7+8 are empty and train 2 is on station 5.
However, you proposal is clear and ok for me s well.

Comment: Please edit your question so the explanation of your input is clear.

Comment: The snag with your input format is that it is only possible to have 1 train starting or stopping at a station.  I guess that answers the question I asked on Aug 23 ( which you have so far ignored ) no more than one train can occupy a station at a time.

Comment: You still have not edited your question :-(.  Anyway, I have added code to read an input file with one station per line. https://github.com/JamesBremner/shunter/commit/9020102f2c1ce478787aa80d405175bec83bec14

Answer (score 0):

I think that the shunting problem can be solved using the **dynamic programming algorithm**.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming especially the 'Computer Science' section.

The sub-problems are choosing the optimal next movement of the train(s) being shunted toward a destination.  This can be done using the BFS approach ( which you say you have solved ) in a subgraph where the vertices representing station occupied by stationary trains have been removed.